# How to tell code analysis that a lambda is only called on a specific platform (to prevent platform compatibility warnings)?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I'm writing code that has to run on Windows and macOS, and I have a builder class where certain operations are only possible on Windows (these cases are annotated with `[SupportedOSPlatform("windows")]`).

Now, to properly handle these cases I'd have to check for the current platform, like

```
[SupportedOSPlatform("windows")]
SomeRestrictedMethod() {}

...

if (OperatingSystem.IsWindows())
{
    myBuilder.Add(SomeRestrictedMethod);
}
```

and everything is fine.

However, I don't want to sprinkle everything with `OperatingSystem.IsWindows()` so I tried to add a method to my builder class that does the guard check for me:

```
class MyBuilder
{
    public MyBuilder Add(...) { ... }

    public MyBuilder WindowsOnly(Action<MyBuilder> action)
    {
        if (OperatingSystem.IsWindows())
        {
            action(this);
        }

        return this;
    }     
}
```

and use it like this:

```
myBuilder
    .Add(SomeMethod)
    .WindowsOnly(b => b
        .Add(SomeRestrictedMethod) // CA1416: Validate platform compatibility
    )
    .Build();
```

Unfortunately, this will trigger *CA1416: Validate platform compatibility* and I can't figure out how to get the analyzer to cooperate. I tried playing around with the `SupportedOSPlatformGuard` attribute, but it doesn't prevent the diagnostic if I apply it to the `WindowsOnly` method, and it can't be applied to parameters it seems, so I can't use it on `Action<MyBuilder> action` either.

Is there a way to make this pattern work without the analyzer complaining, and without disabling this diagnostic globally?

Comment: Have you read the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1416#how-to-fix-violations)? There are 4 ways to fix violations.

Comment: @shingo I have, and none of them apply to my use case, that's why I'm asking the question here.